# Grouping data by specific observations in R

Tags: r

I want to create a new variable that's derived from specific values in my existing variables. My data frame looks something like the following:

```
year <- c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015")
x <- c(2980, 2955, 3110, 2962, 2566, 3788)
y <- c(2453, 2919, 2930, 2864, 2873, 3031)
df <-  data.frame(year, x, y)
```

More specifically, I want to create a third column, `z`, that is the ratio of `x` and `y`. However, I don't want to create this ratio by simply dividing `x` by `y` for each individual year. Instead, I want the values in 2015 (and 2014 etc.) to be an average of this ratio in the three preceding years, i.e. 2014, 2013, and 2012.

I've looked at Wickham's `dplyr` package and, in particular, the `group_by` function but I'm stumped because I don't want to group my data by year per se but by each years' three preceding years as illustrated (hopefully) above.

Comment: Calculate the raw ratio and then do a [rolling average](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+rolling+average). If you have only one data point per year then you don't need any grouping at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers that use `zoo::rollmean` are all on the correct track, but they have a couple of "off by one" errors in them. First, you actually want `zoo::rollmeanr( ..., na.pad=TRUE )` which will correctly pad the output with `NA` on the left side:

```
> zoo::rollmeanr( df$x / df$y, 3, na.pad=TRUE )
[1]        NA        NA 1.0962018 1.0359948 0.9962648 1.0590378
```

The second "off by one" error arises from alignment of this vector with the rest of your data. From your description, you want the value for 2015 to be the average of 2014, 2013, and 2012. However, appending the vector above to your table will make the value for 2015 to be the average of 2015, 2014, and 2013, instead. To correct, you want to omit the last value in your input to the rolling average and prepend an NA to compensate:

```
> c( NA, zoo::rollmeanr( head(df$x / df$y,-1), 3, na.pad=TRUE ) )
[1]        NA        NA        NA 1.0962018 1.0359948 0.9962648
```

Putting it all together using `dplyr` notation:

```
df %>% mutate( z = c( NA, zoo::rollmeanr( head(x/y,-1), 3, na.pad=TRUE ) ) )
  year    x    y         z
1 2010 2980 2453        NA
2 2011 2955 2919        NA
3 2012 3110 2930        NA
4 2013 2962 2864 1.0962018
5 2014 2566 2873 1.0359948
6 2015 3788 3031 0.9962648
```

Comment: Or perhaps this variation:  `library(zoo); transform(df, z = rollapplyr(x/y, list(-seq(3)), mean, fill = NA))`

Answer (score 1):

With dplyr and `library(zoo)`:

```
df_fin<- df %>% mutate( z = rollmeanr(x/y,3,na.pad=TRUE))
```

I think the column z is what you want but it would be good to have the desired output.

Comment: This is slightly incorrect, because it pads with `NA` at both ends, resulting in an "off by 1" error. You want `rollmeanr` to align the values to the right of the padding.

Comment: Gotitedited. Oh sorry ! Got it .. edited @Rich Scriven.

Answer (score 0):

```
df$z<-0
for (i in 4:6){
  df$z[i]<-mean(df$x[(i-3):(i-1)])/mean(df$y[(i-3):(i-1)])
}
```

Whit a loop, you can get this:

```
  year    x    y        z
1 2010 2980 2453 0.000000
2 2011 2955 2919 0.000000
3 2012 3110 2930 0.000000
4 2013 2962 2864 1.089497
5 2014 2566 2873 1.036038
6 2015 3788 3031 0.996654
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(z = x/y, zz = rollmean(z, 3, fill = NA)
```

Comment: please clearly explain, how your answer solves original question.